# Which of my magento 2 extensions that changed my product page layout?

Tags: product, extensions, page

**once i downloaded one of the extensions that viewed in the image that attached .. it had change my product page layout .. and make the product image appears in different column and different size .. so i need to know which extensions made that change .. i need to get the default configuration of my magneto 2 system to be effective again and remove the extension .... 
 thanks**

[image]

note : the default configuration of product page not effect my layout product page anymore

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would search for all the files named catalog_product_view.xml in your project and check if one of those files are in one of your module list. Then try to disable those modules one by one like Shoaib Munir said.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to list down all the enabled and disabled module by this command:

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

After that you need to disable your newly added modules one by one by this (Instead of Vendor_Module use your module name):

```
php bin/magento module:disable Vendor_Module
```

Run following commands after disabling modules

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Once you find out the module that is effecting product page layout then enable all the disabled modules which are not effecting page layout and you have disabled it for testing

```
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module
```

Then run `upgrade` `di:compile` and `deployment` command again.